Newest Chrome version crashes when running test
Since i've updated to the newest chrome version (Version 127.0.6533.73), when i run the test, before chrome is even loaded, the test crashes and throws following error: Error: WebSocket connection closed.
I installed the chrome-for-testing since you can downgrade to an older version with this. This kinda works eventhough its also weird
Does anyone have the same problem or even a fix for this?

It happened to us since the version 127.0.6533.73 but in a different context. A POST request that contained a formdata with one of its fields with content/type not specified (E.G application/json and application/pdf in same payload, but one of them not specified), is causing chrome crash. I don't know if it applies to you but i'm mentioning it in case anyone is affected by the same thing. Maybe test is doing the same.

I am working with version 2.6.2 and in another project with version 3.5.0.
In version 2.6.2, the error does not occur when I run TestCafe without the --native-automation parameter. The browser launches, but I have to manually select the default search engine every time, which is terribly annoying (I don't know how to bypass this).
In version 3.5.0, it runs as described above when I disable native automation using the --disable-native-automation parameter ...but it ends with another error

The current solution is to add the flag: --disable-search-engine-choice-screen.
You can read about it here.

I am using the same version which got its update today and i started getting this Error.
Aug 05, 2024 6:15:49 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.WebSocket$Listener onError
WARNING: Connection reset
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:403)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.implRead(SocketChannelImpl.java:435)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:493)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube.readAvailable(SocketTube.java:1178)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.read(SocketTube.java:841)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowTask.run(SocketTube.java:181)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler$SchedulableTask.run(SequentialScheduler.java:207)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:280)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.common.SequentialScheduler.runOrSchedule(SequentialScheduler.java:233)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$InternalReadSubscription.signalReadable(SocketTube.java:782)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$InternalReadPublisher$ReadEvent.signalEvent(SocketTube.java:965)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.SocketTube$SocketFlowEvent.handle(SocketTube.java:253)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.handleEvent(HttpClientImpl.java:1476)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.lambda$run$3(HttpClientImpl.java:1421)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1597)
at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.HttpClientImpl$SelectorManager.run(HttpClientImpl.java:1421)

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I have the same problem with testcafe using last Chrome update, so I run my test using Edge

worked like a charm
